# When I tried to play a sound from my app I got an AudioPlayerException

Tags: audio-player, flutter-audioplayers

When I play a sound in my project, I get this AudioPlayerException:

[image: its a screenshot for the error]

```
AudioPlayers Exception: AudioPlayerException(
        AssetSource(path: sounds/numbers/number_one_sound.mp3),
        PlatformException(WebAudioError, Failed to set source. For troubleshooting, see
        https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/troubleshooting.md, MediaError: MEDIA_ELEMENT_ERROR: Format error (Code: 4),
        null)
```

I have tried to change the syntax of the path in the `pubspec.yaml` file but it's not working.

Comment: Can you provide the pubspec.yaml where you defined the asset folder?

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), and  [How do I ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)